# change flash youtube to embeded object

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, youtube

I am using a lazy load for my youtube trailers however, I noticed that it does not work on mobile devices I think this is because its flash not object?

can this function bed changed into making it embed as an object?

```
  $('a.youtube-video').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var videoId = $(this).attr('data-video');
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", allowFullScreen: "true" };
    var atts = { id: 'player_'+videoId };
    $(this).hide();
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "http://www.youtube.com/v/"+videoId+"?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3", 
        'placeholder_'+videoId, "100%", "315", "8", null, null, params, atts);

});
```

Any help would be great...

This is the full code:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.youtube-video').each(function() {
    var videoId = $(this).attr('data-video');
    var videoThumbnail = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/0.jpg";
    var videoBackground = $('<span class="youtube-thumbnail"></span>');
    videoBackground.css({
        background:"#fff url('"+videoThumbnail+"') no-repeat",          
backgroundSize: 'cover'

    });

    // also set the parent container size to prevent flicker
    $(this).add($(this).parent()).css({
        height:315,
        width:"100%",
        position:"relative",
        display:"block",
        textAlign:"center",
        color:"#fff",
        fontSize:26


    });
    $(this).text('Click to load video');
    $(this).append(videoBackground);
});

$('a.youtube-video').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var videoId = $(this).attr('data-video');
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", allowFullScreen: "true" };
    var atts = { id: 'player_'+videoId };
    $(this).hide();
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "http://www.youtube.com/v/"+videoId+"?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3", 
        'placeholder_'+videoId, "100%", "315", "8", null, null, params, atts);

});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a.youtube-video').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var videoId = $(this).attr('data-video');
    $("#player_" + videoId).html('<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```

Comment: hmm that looks like it should work but it doesnt do any thing? do I need an iframe already made where I want the video?

Comment: No, just add an empty div with corresponding id or create it on a fly.

Comment: not sure why this wont work... 
this is the code for the div

<div class=\"container\">
    <div id=\"placeholder_" . $videosun['results'][$counter3]['key'] . "\"></div>
    <a href=\"#\" data-video=\"" . $videosun['results'][$counter3]['key'] . "\" class=\"youtube-video\"></a>
</div></div>";

Comment: ahh just spotted the problem the div is called placeholder_